# PrimeNG <p-table> global filter is not working in angular

Tags: primeng

`<p-table #dt [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="232px" [columns]="cols" [value]="packageList" selectionMode="single" [responsive]="true"
[paginator]="false" [rows]="noOfRow" sortField="id" sortOrder="-1" 
[lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadPackageList($event)"                [totalRecords]="totalRecords">`

I have entered code here to use this much attribute.
I need to use global filter but it is not working.
`<input type="text" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Global Filter" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" style="width:auto">`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some code testing, I found an issue, that I have used lazy attribute.
`[lazy]="true"` because of filterGlobal is not working. I did conditionally `true /false` to lazy parameter. when `lazy="false"` then only filterGlobal is working like a charm.